# Impedir que subdominio se redirija a dominio principal

Tags: .htaccess, http

He creado un subdominio **es.dominio.es** pero cuando lo introduzco en la barra de direcciones me lleva a **dominio.es**

Mi archivo .htaccess es:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://dominio.es/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Me lo pasaron los de 1and1 para redirigir http a https.
He probado a borrarlo pero se sigue redireccionando. He buscado en todas partes pero soy incapaz de solucionarlo.

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me ha funcionado!

Answer (score 0):

Cuando el request viene por el puerto 80 (usualmente http)

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
```

Lo rediriges explícitamente al apex (dominio.es)

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://dominio.es/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Con lo cual pasas por alto el subdominio

La regla de redirección debiera ser:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Esto es: si el request no es via https (sea el puerto que sea), lo rediriges **a la misma url pero con https**, manteniendo el host en vez de forzar el apex.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Las dos soluciones que habéis aportado funcionan perfectamente.